# How to change the block time in Quorum (JP Morgan's Ethereum blockchain)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, quorum

Currently the block time among blocks is 20 seconds in average, how can reduce this 20 seconds parameter?

I know there are disadvantages when reduce the block time to 5 seconds or less, my intention is reduce to 10 or 12 seconds.

In private Ethereum blockchains it was possible to change the block time, changing the CalculateDifficult function, but since Quorum has changed to Voting-consensus the difficult has no impact in the block time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to change it

according to the help, there are two arguments for geth command line:

```
geth --help 

  --minblocktime value        Set minimum block time (default: 3)
  --maxblocktime value        Set max block time (default: 10)
```

the values are in seconds.

Comment: You have different flags for raft or ibft!! you'll see them when starting the node